# How to edit Django Crispy field names

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to edit field names that come with (probably) crispy forms but I cannot find the file anywhere.

This is my post_form.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %} 
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Post</legend>
                
                
                {{ form.media }}
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
                

                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I tried to find it from inspect I did find where I wanna change but when I search that file in my project I cannot find it anywhere.

I want to change this Content* to Body

[image: I want to change this Content* to Body]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's your form field's label and Crispy has little to do with that.

If you're using a model form, use `Meta.labels` as [described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        labels = {'content': 'Body'}
```

If you're using a regular form and have defined the fields by hand, set `label=` on the `content` field.

You can also of course set the `verbose_name` of the underlying model field.